# WCF Async - How to use ManualResetEvent

Tags: wcf, manualresetevent

Can any one tell me how to use 'ManualResetEvent' in a async wcf service? I have a console application which makes calls to async wcf service and I wanted to close the console app after  'oncomplete' event finishes.

If possible please provide me a sample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd write your Console App something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false); // Create the wait handle

    static void Main()
    {
        using(var client = CreateYourClient())
        {
            client.MethodCompleted += MethodCompleted;
            client.MethodAsync(); // Start method

            exitEvent.WaitOne(); // Block until the method is done...
        } 
    }

    static void MethodCompleted(object sender, MethodCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
       // Do your work...

       // At this point, signal that the console can close...
       exitEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

However, if you're just doing a single method call, it's probably better to just make it synchronous.  This would only really be beneficial if you're calling multiple asynchronous methods simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Reed. I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks for your help.